# Timestamp in nginx logs changed after upgrading from 1.4.6 to 1.8.1

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I have set the nginx timezone in `/etc/init.d/nginx`:

```
export TZ='Asia/Kolkata'
```

and the timestamp in the logs was working fine.

Later upgraded the nginx to 1.8.1 from 1.4.6 and see the log timestamp got restored to the UTC timestamp. Any ideas?

Comment: Double check the server timezone is still set, sometimes my server "forgets".  Post a log before and after, your nginx configuration, and if possible your ubuntu timezone configuration (though not 100% sure how that work, if you can post it).